# I'm not able to mock a function inside Jest NodeJS module

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, mocking

I have a module that I created with NodeJS and inside it I call a function with the name **existsObject** to check if a file exists within Google Storage.

I'm testing my application with Jest 29.1.2 and for it not to actually perform this function and go get it from storage I'm trying to create a Mock.

The problem is that I tried in countless ways to mock (including with spyOn too) this function that I call inside my module but no way it respected this rule and always sought directly from the storage. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I'll post my code below:

**storage.js**

```
import config from '../config/config.js';
import { storage, bucket } from '../connections/storage.js';

async function existsObject (directory) {

    const exists = await bucket.object(directory).exists();

    return exists;

}

async function getObject (directory) {

    const getObject = await bucket.object(directory).get();

    return getObject;
}

async function  insertObject (localPath, remotePath) {

    const insert = await bucket.object(remotePath).insertFile(localPath);

    return insert;
}

async function insertObjectContent (content, remotePath) {

    const insert = await storage.insert(content, config.bucket+'/'+remotePath);

    return insert;
}

async function deleteObject (directory) {

    const deleteObject = await bucket.object(directory).delete();

    return deleteObject;
}

export { existsObject, getObject, insertObject, insertObjectContent, deleteObject };
```

**existsPrivatekey.js** (this is the file i want to test)

```
import config from '../config/config.js';
import fs from 'node:fs';
import { existsObject } from '../functions/storage.js';

export default async function (domain, where = 'local') {

    if(where == 'local'){

        if(fs.existsSync(config.certificates_dir + '/' + domain + '/' + config.certificates.private)){

            return true;

        }else{

            return false;
        }

    }else{

        if(await existsObject(domain + '/' + config.certificates.private)){

            return true;

        }else{

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**existsPrivatekey.spec.js** (file of test)

```
import { jest } from '@jest/globals';
import existsPrivatekey from '../../helpers/existsPrivatekey.js';

describe('[existsPrivatekey] Check if exists privatekey', () => {

    it('Exists privatekey in Storage', async () => {

        /* Mock tentativa 1 */

        const existsObject = jest.fn();

        existsObject.mockReturnValue(true);

        jest.mock('../../functions/storage.js', () => {
            return existsObject;
        });




        const existsPrivatekeyResult = await existsPrivatekey('meudominio.com.br', 'bucket');

        expect(existsPrivatekeyResult).toBe(true);
    });

    it('Not Exists privatekey in Storage', async () => {

        const existsPrivatekeyResult = await existsPrivatekey('meudominio.com.br', 'bucket');

        expect(existsPrivatekeyResult).toBe(false);
    });
});
```

I had tried several other possibilities and none worked. I need help on this to continue my tests, without it depending on the actual result of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The mock should return the object with methods (module) and you are just returning a mock function.

Try this (and define it outside the test after imports):

```js
jest.mock('../../functions/storage.js', () => {
    const originalModule = jest.requireActual('../../functions/storage.js');

    return {
        ...originalModule, // if you need other original methods from this module 
        existsObject: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(true), // because the existsObject is an async method use here `mockResolvedValue`
    }
});
```

if you want to change the value of mocked `existsObject` then you can define the mock like this:

```
const mockExistsObject = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('test');
jest.mock('../../functions/storage.js', () => {
    const originalModule = jest.requireActual('../../functions/storage.js');

    return {
        ...originalModule, // if you need other original methods from this module 
        existsObject: () => mockExistsObject(),
    }
});
```

So the whole mock and updated test would look like this:

```js
const mockExistsObject = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(false);
jest.mock("../../functions/storage.js", () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual("../../functions/storage.js");

  return {
    ...originalModule,
    existsObject: () => mockExistsObject(),
  };
});

describe("[existsPrivatekey] Check if exists privatekey", () => {
  it("Exists privatekey in Storage", async () => {
    mockExistsObject.mockResolvedValue(true);
    const existsPrivatekeyResult = await existsPrivatekey(
      "meudominio.com.br",
      "bucket"
    );
    expect(existsPrivatekeyResult).toBe(true);
  });

  it("Not Exists privatekey in Storage", async () => {
    mockExistsObject.mockResolvedValue(false);
    const existsPrivatekeyResult = await existsPrivatekey(
      "meudominio.com.br",
      "bucket"
    );
    expect(existsPrivatekeyResult).toBe(false);
  });
});
```